# Expandablelistview different images for groups and childs

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have basic `expandablelistview` and would like to know how to make each child and group have different images. Do I need to somehow modify expandable list adapter? Any help, thoughts, comments will be appreciated. Thanks :)

MainActivity:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{
           .....
public static final Integer[] images = {
            R.drawable.vegetables,
            R.drawable.fruits,
            R.drawable.drinks,
            R.drawable.dessert

        };

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        }
```

}

**My adapter**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

         final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

          if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
          TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
          txtListChild.setText(childText);

          ImageView imgListChild= (ImageView) convertView
                  .findViewById(R.id.IV_childImage);

// I could store images somehow in two dimensional array and then depending on that draw their reference id.
//          imgListChild.setImageResource();

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


         String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
            ImageView imgListGroup= (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.IV_group);

            imgListGroup.setImageResource(MainActivity.images[groupPosition]);

            return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }










}
```

Comment: same issue need help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431114/how-to-add-image-in-expandablelistivew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an `ImageView` in `list_group` and  `list_item` xml files and set image to those ImageViews in your Adapter Class.

Like you are setting the text to `TextView`, in the same way you can set the image to `ImageView`

```
TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
          txtListChild.setText(childText);
ImageView imgListChild = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.image);

            imgListChild.setImageResource(R.drawable.imagename);
```

and your xml file should be

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="32dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textAlignment="textEnd"
    android:textStyle="bold" >


</CheckedTextView> 

    <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/IV_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"   
    android:contentDescription="group image"    

        />
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT:**

There are many ways to store image paths\ Resource IDs.The simplest way is to store them in `ArrayList` and `HashMap`.

Declare a new ArrayList and HashMap to store Resource IDs for Group and Child items.

```
public List<Integer> groupImages;
public HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> childImages;
```

populate it in your `prepareListData()` function.

```
groupImages= new ArrayList<Integer>();
         groupImages.add(R.drawable.vegetables);
         groupImages.add(R.drawable.fruits);
         groupImages.add(R.drawable.drinks);
         groupImages.add(R.drawable.deserts);

         childImages = new HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>();
         List<Integer> vegetablesi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Tomatoes);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Potatoes);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Cucumbers);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Pumpkins);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Peppers);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Onions);
         vegetablesi.add(R.drawable.Garlic);

         List<Integer> fruitsi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Strawberries);
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Blackcurrants);
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Redcurrant);
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Gooseberry);
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Kiwifruit);
         fruitsi.add(R.drawable.Grape);


         List<Integer> drinksi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         drinksi.add(R.drawable.Vodka);
         drinksi.add(R.drawable.Milk);
         drinksi.add(R.drawable.Water);
         drinksi.add(R.drawable.CocaCola);
         drinksi.add(R.drawable.Sprite);


         List<Integer> desertsi = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         desertsi.add(R.drawable.Vodka);
         desertsi.add(R.drawable.Milk);
         desertsi.add(R.drawable.Water);
         desertsi.add(R.drawable.CocaCola);
         desertsi.add(R.drawable.Sprite);


         childImages.put(groupImages.get(0), vegetablesi);
         childImages.put(groupImages.get(1), fruitsi);
         childImages.put(groupImages.get(2), drinksi);
         childImages.put(groupImages.get(3), desertsi);
```

In `getGroupView` and `getChildView` functions you can access those images in this way:

```
@Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
            View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
            }

            TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
            lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IV_group);
            int imageId = this.groupImages.get(groupPosition);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

            return convertView;
    }





@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition,final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {

         final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

          if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
            }
          TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
          txtListChild.setText(childText);

          ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.IV_child);
          int imageId = this.childImages.get(this.groupImages.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
          imageView.setImageResource(imageId);

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but how to achieve this "set image to those ImageViews in your Adapter Class"? :) Thank you for help by the way :)

Comment: Ohh... you mean I should do that in `getChildView` and `getGroupView` for child and group images to add? :) That looks promising I will try and get back to you

Comment: Yes..You should do it in both `getChildView` and `getGroupview`

Comment: Sorry for dumb questions, I am new and just double checking if I understood correctly. :)

Comment: One thing, I my group xml is `CheckedTextView` and I have some difficulties adding imageView, could you tell me what I do wrong? Updated above

Comment: That was not a dumb question..It's ok!

Comment: Don't add `ImageView` inside `CheckedTextView`

Comment: But then my ImageView will need root element. Maybe I could create linear layout and then inside it CheckedTextView and ImageView?

Comment: Yes..you are right..Inside `LinearLayout` or `Relativelayout` you should keep your `CheckedTextView` and `ImageView`

Comment: Then I get `the markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed` error

Comment: Have edited the answer...added a Linearlayout to xml file..check if it works

Comment: working, now just wondering how to do different image for every Group?

Comment: I added images reference id to array and trying to attach images with that. My problem is that those images will be added every time view is inflated not only first time :/. I edited

Comment: Edited. I solved this this way, please advise if it is best way? Or if there is a more simple one?

Comment: Also still looking for how to do the same on childView :/

Comment: Yes, that was my idea too, just wanted to be clear or maybe advised if there is a more simple way :). Thank you very much for everything :)

Comment: As far as I know that is the simplest way...pleasure to help:)

Comment: can any one help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431114/how-to-add-image-in-expandablelistivew

Answer (score 1):

In the getChildView-method you can identify the actual sublistitem through the signature of the method - the variables childPosition and groupPosition.

And from that you can use a switch-structure to load the relevant images.

Comment: can u help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431114/how-to-add-image-in-expandablelistivew