# How to set different images in Expandable ListView parents?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview

I made an ExpandableListView and now I want to set different images in each group. For example, in the Dress group I want to set a photo of a dress, in Shoes a photo of a shoe etc.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingStart="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"/>



        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#f30f30"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

code:

```
package com.example.user.expandablelist;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyExpandableAdapter  extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;


    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        }





        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

code:

```
package com.example.user.expandablelist;


import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ExpandableListActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();

        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();

        MyExpandableAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(this);
}

    public void setGroupParents() {
        parentItems.add("Shorts" );
        parentItems.add("Trousers");
        parentItems.add("Skirts");
        parentItems.add("Dresses");
        parentItems.add("Shoes");

    }


    public void setChildData() {

        // Shirts
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Basic T-Shirts" );
        child.add("Printed T-shirts");
        child.add("Tops");
        child.add("Long-Sleeved Shirts");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Trousers
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Jeans");
        child.add("Casual");
        child.add("Business");
        child.add("Shorts");
        child.add("Leggings");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Skirts
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Mini");
        child.add("Maxi");
        child.add("Midi");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Dresses
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Mini");
        child.add("Maxi");
        child.add("Midi");
        child.add("Weddings & Parties");
        childItems.add(child);

        // Shoes
        child = new ArrayList<>();
        child.add("Sneakers");
        child.add("High-Heels");
        child.add("Wedges");
        child.add("Sandals");
        childItems.add(child);


    }

}
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29431114/how-to-add-image-in-expandablelistivew/29434147#29434147

Answer (score 0):

Use linear layout with custom row.

This video gives a detailed explanation https://youtu.be/AT_FvelNE_Q

```
 Public view getView  (int position, View convert, ViewGroup parent){
View customView = [INSERT INFLATER METHOD);
string single =getItem(position);
TextView yourtext =(TextView)                     customView.findViewById (R.id.text);
 ImageView image =       (ImageView)customView.findViewById (R.id.image);
  Image.setImageResource  (R.drawable.picofcat);
  yourtext.setText ("ayy lmao");
  }
```